# How to shape an image elliptically in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to figure out how to shape images elliptically in Xamarin.Forms. I have been looking at the [ImageCirclePlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin). However, it cannot be used for this purpose. I have also tried with an Ellipse and ImageBrush element as Fill brush. That didn't work:

```
<Ellipse Width="100" Height="100">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Photo}"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Ellipse and ImageBrush could not be found.

Comment: your best bet would be to look at the source of the plugin and modify it to meet your needs.  You're not going to be able to this natively in Forms - it will have to be done at the platform level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FFImageLoading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading) and add the transformation Effect you need. Asides image effects, it can essentially help you manage images efficiently. Don't forget to add the FFImageLoading.Transformations package as well.

Comment: Have tried with different values for the `BottomLeftCornerSize BottomRightCornerSize TopLeftCornerSize TopRightCornerSize`. However, couldn't get the shape of an ellipse

Comment: CornersTransformation with `CropWidthRatio` / `CropHeightRatio` properties correctly set

Answer (score 0):

There's a way of doing this now in Xamarin Forms 5. This of course also applies to the new MAUI framework.

Just add `Image.Clip` to the Image as shown here:

```
<Image Source="default_user.png"
       WidthRequest="80"
       HeightRequest="80">
       <Image.Clip>
           <EllipseGeometry                                
                    Center="40,40"
                    RadiusX="40"
                    RadiusY="40"/>
       </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

For center choose where do you want to center your clip.

Usually if you want to center it, just choose half your image size in x, and y coordinates. So if set `WidthRequest="80"`, and `HeightRequest="80"` I'll choose `Center="40,40"`. And the  RadiusX, and RadiusY set it to whatever radius you want for your clip.